# Batik fails on transformations since JRE 1.7.0_25

Tags: java, svg, batik

Since I updated to JRE 1.7.0_25, batik throws exceptions when applyling transformations.

The stacktrace is:

```
java.awt.image.ImagingOpException: Unable to transform src image
at java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp.filter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.genRect(AffineRed.java:193)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AffineRed.copyData(AffineRed.java:109)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2sRGBRed.copyData(Any2sRGBRed.java:166)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractRed.getData(AbstractRed.java:526)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:264)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:455)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:549)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.ShapeNode.paint(ShapeNode.java:143)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.genRect(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:140)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.copyData(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:116)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.PadRed.copyData(PadRed.java:88)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2LsRGBRed.copyData(Any2LsRGBRed.java:109)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.AbstractRed.getData(AbstractRed.java:526)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.CompositeRed.genRect(CompositeRed.java:188)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.CompositeRed.copyData(CompositeRed.java:139)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.Any2sRGBRed.copyData(Any2sRGBRed.java:166)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:347)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:455)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.renderable.PadRable8Bit.paintRable(PadRable8Bit.java:135)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:440)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.renderable.PadRable8Bit.paintRable(PadRable8Bit.java:135)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:440)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.renderable.FilterChainRable8Bit.paintRable(FilterChainRable8Bit.java:251)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.drawImage(GraphicsUtil.java:440)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:549)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CanvasGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CanvasGraphicsNode.java:159)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.AbstractGraphicsNode.paint(AbstractGraphicsNode.java:509)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.CompositeGraphicsNode.primitivePaint(CompositeGraphicsNode.java:165)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.genRect(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:140)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.copyData(GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.java:116)
at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.rendered.TranslateRed.copyData(TranslateRed.java:105)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.DynamicRenderer.repaint(DynamicRenderer.java:244)
at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.repaint(StaticRenderer.java:344)
at org.apache.batik.swing.gvt.GVTTreeRenderer.run(GVTTreeRenderer.java:123)
```

The Exception is thrown at [this line in AffineRed.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.apache.batik.ext/awt/1.6.0/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/image/rendered/AffineRed.java#192).

Does anyone how to fix this or is this a temporary bug in the JRE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [regression](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8019201) in Java 7 Update 25. Aggravatingly, Oracle looks set to delay the fix for the regression until Update 60. It's not like anyone depends on Java for anything. Thanks, Oracle!

There's a brief description in [this post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-batik-users/201307.mbox/%3C51D411A2.9030203@yworks.com%3E) from the Batik mailing list regarding how to avoid the problem:

> The only workaround I have been able to find so far is patching BATIK
> sources to no longer call BufferedImageOp.filter directly on the source
> and destination image, but to filter two ARGB BufferedImage copies.

Regrettably, this means having to make copies of both the source and destination images if they happen not to be ARGB.

Comment: Thanks, I already read about the regression. Fixing Batik - ha ha, there is not really a progress for years.

Comment: There's nothing to fix in Batik. It's not their bug. Batik is using Java as per spec in this case.

Comment: Thomas (the guy who wrote that post) kindly sent me a patch to Batik sources that fixes this problem. He hasn't replied to my email yet so I'm not publishing it, but if somebody else is facing this problem, ping me via email.

Comment: Update: I posted the patch in a sibling answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thomas Behr (the guy who wrote [this post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-batik-users/201307.mbox/%3C51D411A2.9030203@yworks.com%3E)) created a patch that fixes the issue using the workaround described in the [sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829438/458193).

He kindly sent it to me when I asked him, and since numerous people contacted me about this patch, I decided to publish it in good faith that Thomas doesn't mind it.

- **[batik-1.7-filter-patch.zip](http://cl.ly/3y3L2c0B193G)** (53 KB)

Apply it on top of Batik 1.7 sources and you should be fine.